# Can't get an equivalent to std::less to work for nested iterators

Tags: c++, templates, iterator, c++17, constexpr

I am trying to write a nested iterator template. So the idea is that you can iterate over the `int`s of a `std::array<std::array<int, N> M>>` as if it was a single continuous array. But the template would also work with all sorts of other combinations.

Here is a simplified version of my code, which has a minor issue right now:

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <type_traits>
#include <optional>

template <typename T>
struct default_range {
    constexpr auto begin(const T& t) const {
        return t.begin();
    }
    constexpr auto end(const T& t) const {
        return t.end();
    }
    constexpr auto begin(T& t) const {
        return t.begin();
    }
    constexpr auto end(T& t) const {
        return t.end();
    }
};

template <typename Outer, typename OuterRange>
constexpr auto inner_impl() {
    // IMPORTANT: this line is necessary because otherwise OuterRange will always be invoked with the const& version of
    //            begin().
    //            Outer must first be captured in a variable so that we preserve constness properly
    Outer outer = std::declval<Outer>();
    return *std::declval<OuterRange>().begin(outer);
}

template <typename Outer, typename OuterRange>
using inner_t = std::remove_reference_t<decltype(inner_impl<Outer, OuterRange>())>;

template <typename T>
using iterator_value_t = typename std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type;

template <typename OuterIterator,
          typename InnerRange = default_range<std::remove_reference_t<iterator_value_t<OuterIterator>>>>
class nested_iterator {
private:
    using InnerIterator = decltype (std::declval<InnerRange>().begin(*std::declval<OuterIterator>()));

public:
    using self_type = nested_iterator;
    using value_type = iterator_value_t<InnerIterator>;
    using reference = std::remove_reference_t<value_type> &;
    using pointer = std::remove_reference_t<value_type> *;
    using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;
    using difference_type = size_t;

private:
    struct inner_iterators {
        InnerIterator pos;
        InnerIterator end;

        constexpr inner_iterators(InnerIterator pos, InnerIterator end)
            : pos{std::move(pos)}, end{std::move(end)}
        {
        }
    };

    OuterIterator outerPos;
    OuterIterator outerEnd;
    std::optional<inner_iterators> inners = std::nullopt;
    InnerRange innerRange;

public:
    constexpr nested_iterator(OuterIterator outer, OuterIterator outerEnd)
        : outerPos{std::move(outer)}, outerEnd{std::move(outerEnd)}
    {
        // constructor code here
    }

    // operator overloads here

};  // class iterator

template <typename Outer,
          typename OuterRange = default_range<Outer>,
          typename InnerRange = default_range<inner_t<Outer, OuterRange>>>
class nested_iterable {
private:
    using Inner = inner_t<Outer, OuterRange>;

public:
    using outer_iterator = decltype (std::declval<OuterRange>().begin(std::declval<Outer>()));
    using inner_iterator = decltype (std::declval<InnerRange>().begin(std::declval<Inner>()));
    using iterator = nested_iterator<outer_iterator, InnerRange>;

private:
    Outer *outer;
    OuterRange outerRange;

public:
    constexpr nested_iterable(Outer &outer) : outer{&outer} {}

    constexpr iterator begin() const
    {
        return {outerRange.begin(*outer), outerRange.end(*outer)};
    }

    constexpr iterator end() const
    {
        return {outerRange.end(*outer), outerRange.end(*outer)};
    }
};

constexpr void test()
{
    const std::array<std::array<int, 5>, 3> arr{};
    nested_iterable range{arr};
}
```

```
<source>:13:20: error: multiple overloads of 'begin' instantiate to the same signature 'auto (const std::array<std::array<int, 5>, 3> &) const'

    constexpr auto begin(T& t) const {

                   ^

<source>:27:39: note: in instantiation of template class 'default_range<const std::array<std::array<int, 5>, 3> >' requested here

    return *std::declval<OuterRange>().begin(outer);

...

<source>:110:21: note: while substituting deduced template arguments into function template '<deduction guide for nested_iterable>' [with Outer = const std::array<std::array<int, 5>, 3>, OuterRange = (no value), InnerRange = (no value)]

    nested_iterable range{arr};
```

As one can easily tell, `default_range` can't be instantiated for a `const std::array`, because the `begin` and `end` methods become ambiguous when instantiating with a `const` type.

The idea of `default_range` is that it works like a default `std::less` but the user can decide to make their own with `rbegin` being invoked instead.

This appears to be the missing piece of the puzzle right now. I have also tried using a single `begin` instead of overloads for both kinds of references, but this doesn't work either. In that case `T` would always need to be an rvalue-reference.

So how could I implement `default_range` so that it would work with `const` and non-`const` types?

Comment: `ranges::view::join` and `ranges::view::concat` (from range-v3) might  interest you.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I can't use C++20 yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partially-specialize `default_range` for the `const T` case, where you don't overload the problematic functions:

```
template <typename T>
struct default_range<const T> {
    constexpr auto begin(const T& t) const {
        return t.begin();
    }
    constexpr auto end(const T& t) const {
        return t.end();
    }
};
```

Also, note that `std::declval` can only be used in an unevaluated context. Having said that, `inner_impl` needs to be reimplemented, e.g.:

```
template <typename Outer, typename OuterRange>
using inner_impl_t = decltype(*std::declval<OuterRange>().begin(std::declval<Outer&>()));
```